# How to put Shiny app online in my own webpage?

Tags: r, shiny, html

I've a shiny app which works fine the RStudio.

Now I want to put the app online on my own server in a webpage. Can someone tell me how can I do it? Which files should I put on my server folder and how can I lunch the app?

Comment: download `shinyserver` https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/

Comment: I think that shiny server is used for who does not have a server to put the app. A have the server

Comment: No, http://www.shinyapps.io/ is used for those who dont have a server. you still need the `shinyserver` to put it on your machine. See Dean's overview of the Digital Ocean, you're essentially the same 

http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/

Comment: but shinyserver is not windows usable...

Comment: use `Virtual Box` approach, https://github.com/leondutoit/shiny-server-on-ubuntu

Comment: If you have a Windows server, you'll need to use a virtual machine like @PorkChop said, or use `shinyapps.io`. Furthermore, if you want to include your app inside another webpage, you need to use an `iframe`.